# What are current recommended settings for a Microsoft app used with Janrain Single Sign On?

Tags: openid, janrain

[image]I am trying to configure a new **Microsoft** Account for use with **Janrain** (RPX) Single Sign On.  I have Google, Twitter and Yahoo working.  I mention that because it indicates that most of my configuration is valid.

The [Janrain docs for the Microsoft provider](https://docs.janrain.com/social/identity-providers/#microsoft) do not match the current Microsoft screens at all.

I was wondering whether anyone who got the Microsoft provider working some time ago, when the docs must have matched, would be able/willing to log in to their Microsoft dev apps account, and provide a brief guide to the old/new way of referring to the details that are critical to integration with Janrain.

As one example, on the Microsoft apps page, Microsoft has a heading "**App ID / Client Id**".  I assume that mean that the item listed just below must be filled in for the **ClientID** requested by Janrain.  Probably.

Is **Implicit Flow** required? recommended? for use with Janrain ?

For the **Client Secret** required by Janrain when configuring the Microsoft Provider, do you go under Application Secrets on the Microsoft app page, click [Generate New Password], and use that password which is given once right then?

The error message that I am getting is "**Token exchange error for Microsoft Account**."

Is a **sign OUT page** required for use with Microsoft? What did you use for the Sign OUT Url?  A static html page, containing what? I expected this to be a URL that Janrain would tell us to use, not a static page on our site as the little Microsoft help tip indicates.

**Screenshots of the application as configured on my Microsoft panel follow.**

[image: Detail for the Application, part 1]

[image: Detail for the Application, part 2]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Microsoft has changed the UI once again.  I'll open a ticket to have our documentation updated.

The current URL for setting up the Microsoft Login is:
https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/?mkt=en-us&referrer=https%3a%2f%2faccount.live.com#/appList

Here are the steps to create a new login application:

1. Login to the url above
2. Under "Live SDK applications" click the "Add an app" button
3. Give your app an obvious name.
4. Check the "Allow Implicit Flow" checkbox
5. Check the "Restrict token issuing to this app" checkbox
6. Uncheck the "Enhanced redirection security" checkbox
7. Target domain should be something like: "YOUR_ENGAGE_APP_NAME.rpxnow.com"
8. Redirect URL should be something
   like: "https://YOUR_ENGAGE_APP_NAME.rpxnow.com"

I think the Logo, Terms of Service URL and Privacy Statement URL might be optional but if you want to be "professional" then go ahead and fill them in with valid URL's for you web site.

Once you save you changes, the site should give you an Application Id and Application Secret that you can use in the Engage application provider configuration for Microsoft Login.

Comment: THANK YOU. Re 7, I do not see a prompt for target domain.  I set the platform to 'Web' because this is for a members-only website. Re 8, should this end in /liveid/callback or just end with rpxnow.com?  Does Live SDK support matter? Does anything need to be changed in the default manifest?

Comment: Hmmm . . .  when I click on the "Live SDK applications" "Add an app" button I have the "Target Domain" input clearly displayed in my web platform dialog box.  The redirect URL does not need anything on the end - just use something similar to what I posted above.  If you need more help you may need to contact Janrain support at http://support.janrain.com

Comment: Screenshot added above. "Live SDK applications" does not appear as a heading anywhere for me. However within the details of the app, I do have a checkbox for [x] Live SDK and it is enabled.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the details page for a new app (with any secrets or keys deleted/obscured)?  You may just have to try a few different options.  Clearly Microsoft shows a different interface depending on how old your apps are (mine are around 4 years old) or how long you have been a developer (or something like that).

Comment: Yes, screenshots added. Agree; my Microsoft developer account for this project is just a few weeks old with zero history and minimal cookies.

Comment: The screenshots in the Setup Guide for Facebook are out of date as well.

Comment: I don't think you need the "/liveid/callback" on the end of the "Redirect URL's" setting.  Otherwise everything looks correct.  If you change that setting and it doesn't work then let me know and I'll try and set up a new developer account to test with.  I'll let our documentation team know about updating the provider instructions.  Thanks.

Comment: Removing /liveid/callback leads to this error, "We're unable to complete your request. Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later."     I tried 2 minutes later, same error.

Comment: I got around to setting up a new developer account and have experienced the same problems you are seeing.  It appears Microsoft is forcing new developers to use their new "v2" api.  I have filed the necessary support tickets to get this issue resolved but can not provide any estimated schedule for resolution.  Please feel free to file a support ticket at http://support.janrain.com if you feel you need additional assistance.

Comment: Thank you for all the follow-up.   As this is for a non-profit, I have a free basic Janrain account and I believe that locks me out of using the Janrain support system.  I will retest in a week and see if there has been some progress.  If you remember to add a note here when the issue is fixed, great.